# How to apply only valid coupon codes to shopping cart programmatically?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

I have a number of coupon codes which i want to apply to the cart programmatically.

I have done it like this:

```
foreach ($coupons as $coupon) //$coupons array of coupon codes
{
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')
        ->getQuote()
        ->setCouponCode($coupon)
        ->collectTotals()
        ->save();
}
```

Now what happens is that if the first coupon is valid, it got applied, but after that

- if the second coupon is valid, it got replaced (first removed, second applied).
- if the second coupon is not valid it removes the discount applied by the first coupon too.

Now I need help to tackle the situation as how to be able to apply both coupon/rules/discounts if valid (if possible applying two coupon codes)?
or not apply coupon code if not valid so that the coupon applied before doesn't got removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per as magento system,you `cannot apply multiple coupon on a cart`.

If you want then need to use

3rd partly extension like  [amasty](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multiple-coupons-by-amasty.html)

Or

you can use this answer:

[Magento Multiple coupon apply on cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/68043/magento-multiple-coupon-apply-on-cart)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response i will try it and will get back to you with the results. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for your answer (accepted), it works fine on magento ver 1.9 but i am getting White Screen of Death on mag ver 1.8 when i add product to cart.
In apache error log it say, Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262668288 bytes)

Comment: Hi, just need to remove `$items = $this->_calculator->sortItemsByPriority($items);` to get it working on magento ver 1.8.
Thanku :)